# Php backlink checker on another website

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am trying to make a script to check if a webpage has a back link to my page. I have found this script but the problem is that it returns the error message "No back link found" even if there is a backlink. Could someone tell me what is wrong with this script?
Here is the script I am using:

```
    require('simple_html_dom.php');

function CheckReciprocal( $targetUrl, $checkLinkUrl, $checkNofollow = true )
{
    $html = file_get_html($targetUrl);
    if (empty($html))
    {
        //@ Could not load file
        return false;
    }


    $link = $html->find('a[href^='.$checkLinkUrl.']',0);
    if (empty($link))
    {
        //@ Link not found
        return false;
    }


    if ( $checkNofollow && $link->hasAttribute('rel') )
    {
        $attr = $link->getAttribute('rel');
        return (preg_match("/\bnofollow\b/is", $attr) ? false : true);
    }


    return true;
} 

$targetUrl = 'http://example.com/test.html';


$checkLinkUrl = 'http://mysite.com';


if ( CheckReciprocal($test, $checkLinkUrl) )
{
    echo 'Link found';
}
else { echo 'Link not found or marked as nofollow'; }
```

Thank you!

Comment: Show us `a` element from this page.

Comment: @Philippe K thanks for the correction :)

Comment: @kasyx here is the a tag on the test html page <a href="http://mysite.com">My Anchor</a> it is with http : // but it doesent show in comment

Comment: Your code instantiates a value for `$targetUrl` but checks the value of `$test`. Which variable contains the URL that you want to scan?

Comment: but there can be `www` in this link and so on. I think, the problem is that, regexp cannot math this link. You're looking for `http://mysite.com` and he can links to `http://www.mysite.com`

Comment: @GeorgeCummins I didnt noticed that. I have changed to if ( CheckReciprocal($targetUrl, $checkLinkUrl) ) and still the same result

Comment: Ok the problem was that on the test site htaccess rewrited the example.com to www.example.com if i put $targetUrl = 'http : // www.example.com/test.html'; is working

Comment: actually with DomDocument and a bit of regex this could be achieved much easily xd

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how does that simple_html_dom.php's $html->find() works cos never used it, but it seems that your problem is there. I would trust the good ol' DOMDocument + regex.

Just wrote a function and tested it, just use on the $url the plain domain + whatever you want, don't worry about the http(s) or www and stuff like that:

```
function checkBackLink($link, $url, $checkNoFollow = true){
    $dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTMLFile($link);

    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $item){
        if($checkNoFollow){
            if(preg_match('/nofollow/is', $item->getAttribute('rel'))) continue;
        }
        if($item->hasAttribute('href') === false) continue;
        if(preg_match("#^(https?\://)?(www\.)?$url.*#i", $item->getAttribute('href'))) return true;
    }
}

if(checkBacklink('the link', 'example.com')){
    echo "link found";
} else {
    echo "Link not found or marked as nofollow";
}
```

---

If you don't like it and still want to use the simple_html_dom just make sure how that find() works, because if it only match exact values that could be troublesome.

Answer (score 0):

**Bulk Anchor Text & Dofollow / Nofollow Checker**

[image]

It allows you to check backlinks according to the following conditions collectively:

- Anchor text status (pulls all keywords or straight links)
- Dofollow and nofollow status
- HTTP status

**Use of:**

- In the Domain box, you type the domain name to which the backlinks are linked: "example.com."
- In the "Backlink URLs (one per line):" text field, you paste the backlinks one after the other in bulk. (with HTTP or HTTPS).
- Check will check the backlinks you clicked ten by 10. It will show the transaction status as a percentage and how many backlinks are left.

**Project file**: https://github.com/ercanatay/Backlink-Checker.git